# Filtering the array with objects but it doesn't filter the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

**Below is my State in Reactjs Functional Component**

```
let valueByFilterInitState = [{ filterType: "Organization", value: "Micro", id: "15" }, { filterType: "Vehicle", value: "Bmw", id: "13" }]
const [filterListValue, setFilterListValue] = useState(valueByFilterInitState)
```

**Here I am trying to filter the the list but it doesn't filter & returning the same array**

```
const chipHandler = (list) => {

        setFilterListValue(filterListValue => {
            const copy = [...filterListValue]
            let test = copy.filter((val) => {

                if (val.value === list.value) {

                    return { filterType: val.filterType, value: "", id: "" }
                }
                return val
            })

            return test
        })
    }
```

**Here I am rendering those filterListValue**

```
<div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "start", alignItems: "start", columnGap: 4 }}>
                        {
                            filterListValue.filter((selectedFilter) => selectedFilter.id !== "").map((list, index) => {
                                return (<Chip variant="outlined" label={list.value} onDelete={() => chipHandler(list, index)} />)
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
```

Comment: Are you confusing filter with map? `filter` takes truthy/falsey returns to determine if the item in question gets filtered out or not. `map` lets you iterate the array and change the values along the way if desired. The way your code is set up, it returns a truthy value each time, which means nothign is filtered out.

Comment: In addition to what was already pointed to, neither for `filter`ing nor for `map`ping one needs to operate a `copy` of `filterListValue` for both methods do not mutate the original array nor does a mapping (if done properly) mutate any of the original array's items.